# create object and array for json in php

Tags: php, json

How to create a php json with response  as below, which contain one object, one array with 3 items inside?

```
{"files": [
    {
        "name": "picture1.jpg",
        "size": 902604,
        "deleteType": "DELETE"
    }
]}
```

---

now i put as below:

```
 $info= (array ('file'=> array (array(  
       'name' => $name,
       'size' => $data['file_size'],
       'deleteType' => 'DELETE' ) ) ) );
```

echo json_encode(array($info));

and the response as below

```
[
    {
        "file": [
            {
                "name": "1391845241happycny.jpg",
                "size": 233.41,
                "deleteType": "DELETE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

this is not what i want, i don't want the [] before 'file'

the result i want should be

```
{
    "file": [
        {
            "name": "1391845241happycny.jpg",
            "size": 233.41,
            "deleteType": "DELETE"
        }
    ]
}
```

who can help?

Answer (score 1):

## [Visualize it properly :)](http://codepad.org/3b4CZGj3)

```
$array = array('files' => array(array('name' => 'picture1.jpg', 'size' => '902604', 'deleteType' => 'DELETE')));
echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
{"files":[{"name":"picture1.jpg","size":"902604","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

Comment: visualize the missing array

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = 
    array("files"=>
        array(
            array(
                "name"=>"picture1.jpg",
                "size"=>"902604",
                "deleteType"=>"DELETE"
            )
        )
    );
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//{"files": [ { "name": "picture1.jpg", "size": 902604, "deleteType": "DELETE" } ]}


$array  =   array('files'=>( array(array("name"=>"picture1.jpg", "size"=>902604, "deleteType"=>"DELETE" ) )));


echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Yep :P I know now by looking at your answer..thanks !

Comment: the response become [{"files":[{"name":"1391845241happycny.jpg","size":233.41,"deleteType":"DELETE"}]}], got [] before 'files'

Comment: the files become an array, not an object

Comment: @user3286508 no the response is {"files":[{"name":"picture1.jpg","size":902604,"deleteType":"DELETE"}]}

Comment: $info= (array ('file'=> array (array(  
     'name' => $name,
     'size' => $data['file_size'],
     'deleteType' => 'DELETE' ) ) ) ); 
any wrong?

echo json_encode(array($info));

Comment: output is [{"file":[{"name":"1391845241happycny.jpg","size":233.41,"deleteType":"DELETE"}]}]

Comment: @user3286508 FYI the response for me is what I stated before ! no "[" before the json . thanks

Comment: ohh, i know where i wrong, i  echo json_encode(array($info));
should echo json_encode($info);

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode($array);`

Answer (score 0):

$array=
(array
       ("Files"=>
           array
                (array(
                      "name"=>"picture1,jpg",
                      "size"=>902604,
                      "deleteType"=>"DELETE"
                     )
                )
      )
);
json_encode($array);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //{"files": [ { "name": "picture1.jpg", "size": 902604, "deleteType": "DELETE" } ]}

$name = "picture1.jpg";
$size = "902604";
$deleteType = "DELETE";
header('Content-type: application/json');

?>
{
    "files": [{
        "name" : "<?php echo $name; ?>",
        "size" : "<?php echo $size; ?>",
        "deletetype": "<?php echo $deleteType; ?>"
   } ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for this you need to

`echo json_encode(array($your_array));`